Can't get past the main menu of Risk of Rain 2 on PS5
When I load up Risk of Rain 2 on my PS5, the main menu does not respond to any button inputs. I can go up and down on the menu options on the total screen, but pressing accept does nothing. I can't get past the title screen because of this. I've tried restarting the game, reconnecting to the internet, and redownloading the game, but the issue persists.
